# How do I search/replace all "n(" -> "n*(" and ")n" -> ")*n" within same equation?

Tags: regex, swift

Scenario: 
The user can enter any number of parentheses pairs into an equation in String format.  However I need to check to be sure that all parentheses `(` or `)` have an adjacent multiplier symbol `*`.  Hence `3(` should be `3*(` and `)3` should be `)*3`.

I need to replace all occurrences of possible `n(` with `n*(` and `)n` with `)*n`.

*Example*:

```
1+5(3+4)7/2   ---> 1+5*(3+4)*7/2
```

**What is the correct regex what to do this?**

I was thinking of something like `[0-9]\( & \)[0-9]`.

But I don't know the full syntax of search for all assurances of patterns to be replaced with `*` insert.

Comment: Do you want to only insert a `*` between a number and a `(` or `)`? In this case, if you use a regex, you'd need 2 rounds: one with `(?<=\d)\(` (and replace with `*(`, and 2) another with `\)(?=\d)` and `)*` as a replacement.

Comment: You might want to check for `)(` as well if `(1 + 2)(3 + 4)` is possible

Comment: Could there be occurences of `n(` or `)n`, which must not be replaced? Could `(?<=\d)(?=\()|(?<=\))(?=\d)` (See [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/nW0uH4/1)) possibly work for you?

Comment: I didn't think about ')('.  I'm using NSExpression to parse the equation.  It doesn't like ')'+ number.   It needs an operator; hence the regexp search/replace.

Comment: I'm studying RegEx101 (I really need to study RegExp!).  There's another scenario mentioned by Skrundz: ')(' should become ')*('.

Answer (score 0):

*edit* - misread the question.

Didn't see any regex capability in swift, so I assume its using something imported (or visa-versa).

Not using advanced assertions, one way is to do it in two passes.

*Pass 1:*

Find:  `([\d)])(\()`
Replace:  `$1*$2`

*Pass 2:*

Find:  `(\))([\d(])`
Replace:  `$1*$2`

Comment: I had to use Cocoa to parse the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Without the regex pain (but maybe not the most beautiful solution) :

```
equation = '1+5(3+4)7/2'
output = ''

for index, char in enumerate(equation):
    if char == '(' and equation[index-1] != '*' or equation[index-1] == ')' and char != '*':
        output += '*'
    output += char
print('finally:', output)
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Turning a comment into an answer.</sup>

With the input given so far, the following seems to work:

- For the original request regarding `n(`and `)n`:
  `(?<=\d)(?=\()|(?<=\))(?=\d)`
- To handle `)(` as well:
  `(?<=\d)(?=\()|(?<=\))(?=[\d(])`

It uses two sets of positive lookarounds.
It does no verification of any sort to be in the middle of an equation / mathematical term.

See it in action:

- [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/nW0uH4/2) for `n(`and `)n`.
- [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/nW0uH4/3) with `)(` added.

Please comment if adjustment / further detail is required.

Comment: How would you include a test for: ')(' to ')*('?

Comment: One way: In the second alternative, extend the lookahead to allow a range consisting of digits and and opening parenthesis. See updated above.

Comment: I just scanned for ')(' and replace it with ')*(' via NSMutableString.

Comment: No, I would love to learn how to do it in regexp.  In the meantime, I figured that I could do the scan ')(' separately.   But academically, speaking, I would like to master regexp.

Comment: Yes.  Thanks!
I need to study RegExp.   I've been adding your code to my Evernote™ docs for study.